# Python SQLite3 not updating

Tags: python, sqlite

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but my database is not updating! This is what I'm doing, so simple:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('tarefas.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("UPDATE tarefas SET concluido = 1")
conn.commit
conn.close()
```

I want to update all rows in this column. When I execute this query in a sqlite manager it works. Why python just can't?

Comment: I think that's supposed to be `conn.commit()`

Comment: Shame on me!
I was looking for it the whole day. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You miss parentheses in the `conn.commit` call. Try this:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('tarefas.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("UPDATE tarefas SET concluido = 1")
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```